# Django DRF get_queryset, how to join two models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-orm

I have two models, I have to make an endpoint where the results of two tables should appear in the json, which have a fongeringkey that joins them.

My code is the following:
`models.py`

```
class Property(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    price = models.BigIntegerField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'property'

class StatusHistory(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'status_history'
```

`views.py`

```
class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
    page_size_query_param = "page_size"
    max_page_size = 1000

class PropertyListView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'head']
    serializer_class = PropertyListSerializer
    queryset = Property.objects.all()
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return PropertyListSerializer
        return PropertyListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Property.objects.all()
        if self.request.GET.get('year'):
            queryset = queryset.filter(year=self.request.GET.get('year'))
        if self.request.GET.get('city'):
            queryset = queryset.filter(city=self.request.GET.get('city'))
        if self.request.GET.get('status'):
            #what would I do here?
            pass
        
        else:
            queryset = queryset.order_by('-year')
        return queryset

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
            
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class PropertyListSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ('id', 'address', 'city', 'price', 'description', 'year')

class StatusHistoryListSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StatusHistory
        fields = ('property', 'status', 'update_date')
```

I don't know how to filter by get with the parameters, city, year(model Property) and status(model StatusHistory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to filter based in the status of the history you can do the following:

```py
if self.request.GET.get('status'):
    queryset = queryset.filter(statushistory__status=self.request.GET.get('status'))
```

Comment: yes it worked well for me, it already filters by status but it is not shown in the JSON list, do you know how to make the status of HistoryStatus appear in the JSON result, thanks

Comment: yeah create a new property in the `PropertyListSerializer` called `statushistory_set =StatusHistoryListSerializer(many=True) ` not pretty sure about the whole code but you can link a new question here to dig into it more if that doesn't work...

Comment: Also you have to add that `statushistory_set` to the `fields` tuple to be displayed.